# Web Component(LWC) in Flow(Screen) Salesforce

Tags: visual-flows

How I can to use Lighting Web Component(LWC) in Flow(Screen) Salesforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWC is not supported yet with flow. See [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_experiences) for this. You have to use Aura component for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: For those coming along later, LWC Components are now supported in Flows as of Winter 20.  Documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_flow_screens